# React Native - Dismiss Menu on Any Touch Event

Tags: react-native, touch-event

I would like to have a small menu that closes if the user interacts with any other component. For example if the user tries to scroll or interact with any of the content in a scrollview behind the menu (see the image below for reference).

[image: Reference]

I have two ideas for how this might be achieved:

1. A transparent layer behind the menu with an absolute position and dimensions matching the device. If this layer registers a touch event the menu can be dismissed. The problem with this is that from the users perspective the touch event was totally ignored. So for this to work well I would need to be able to still pass the touch event through the absolute layer to the content behind it.
2. Add callbacks to every component that could be interacted with to notify the menu that it should close. This option seems like it would be very messy and because of the large number of components in my use case it is not practical to implement and maintain.

Is there an other proper way to solve this problem? Can any of the issues I raised with the ideas above be resolved or mitigated?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your view with a TouchableWithoutFeedback component and provide it a onPress callback that hides the menu if it's open. Depending on how top-level the 'expand' icon is, you may want to track the menu's visibility in redux and dispatch an action onPress to track globally.